# How to execute main window key binding when child window is focussed in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have binded the key binding to my wpf main window as below,

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F2" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Normally it executes fine. If any new child window is opened(currently focused) means, the main window key binding not works.

I know, key binding will execute for focused item only, But here i want to execute even if it is not focused. Any way to do this and if it is possible please share your idea to me.

This is serious issue to me.

Any one please provide your suggestion?

Comment: My WPF application suffers from this problem, but I think that this is normal... if you look at Visual Studio for instance: Open a child window, like the Exceptions window... now press F6 to build... it doesn't work. Now close the window and try again... it works. However, I'd still be interested to find out if there *is* a solution to this. +1

Answer (score 1):

[WPF Behavior: Global Application Shortcut Keys](http://blogs.southworks.net/geoff/2011/03/15/wpfshortcutkeys/)

Seems to be what you're looking for. I made a couple small modifications to the author's code to get your required functionality(rather than passing in an `InputBindings` collection, made the `Behavior` pick it from the `AssociatedObject` directly. Also took out the restriction for requiring modifier keys, Although I suggest you do read through the author's notes in the article and incorporate it to your requirements)

[**Sample download for your requirements**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlwzg8hejbcrdte/MvvmLight33.rar)

^^ I could get your required behavior, however do go through the `Behavior<T>` to see if you can optimise it better for yourself(only bit's I actually looked into was just stuff relating to your specific requirement.)